# Missing localforage.js files when installing localforage-cordovasqlitedriver into my project

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, localforage, sqlite2

I am trying to get [localforage-cordovasqlitedriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localforage-cordovasqlitedriver) presented within my IOS/IONIC/Cordova project so that I can access it and change all my localstorge.setitem(key,value) and localstorge.getitem(key,value) commands to localforage.setitem(key,value) and localforage.getitem(key,value)and have it use SQLite.

After successfully installing the components and building the project, the localforage-cordovasqlitedriver instructions indicate that there is a localforage.js file and a localforage-cordovasqlitedriver.js in the /lib/* folder of the project.

However, those files are not present in my project, even though I successfully installed the components.

My Project’s /lib folder

[image]

I searched not just that folder, but the whole folder architecture of the /www/ areas of project where I installed the components per the localforage-cordovasqlitedriver instructions , and I cannot find either of the two files anywhere.

Clearly, I am doing something wrong.

I am hoping to find someone who has done this before and knows exactly what I need to do, and can provide some guidance or help, which I would greatly appreciate.

I made a detailed video, posted below, showing the entire process up to the point where I build the project and then search for the two files.

https://www.aloye.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/localforage/LocalForageIssue.mp4

I am hoping the details in that video will enable someone with the right level of expertise to tell me exactly what I did wrong, and what I need to do specifically so that those files are present.

If I compare the contents of my project, to the [Ionic/Cordova Test Project on Github](https://github.com/thgreasi/localForage-cordovaSQLiteDriver-TestIonicApp) my app is missing the www/lib/localforage and www/lib/localForage-cordovaSQLiteDriver folder.

Test Project From Github’s /lib folder

[image]

Unfortunately, I am unable to build the Ionic/Cordova Test Project referenced above because it includes angular and several other components that I do not use and do not need, and those components introduce numerous dependency errors and issues, so rather than troubleshoot all that, I thought it would be easier to install only localforage-cordovasqlitedriver and the pre-requsite components into my production project, instead of all the extra material in the test project.

I am hoping to find someone with the right level of expertise that can quickly and easily tell me exactly what I need to do to get this working.

I simply want to get localforage-cordovasqlitedriver presented within my IOS/IONIC/Cordova project so that I can access it and change all my localstorge.setitem(key,value) and  localstorge.getitem(key,value)commands to localforage.setitem(key,value) and localforage.getitem(key,value)and have it use SQLite.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself.

I was able to copy the localforage and localforage-cordovasqlitedriver folders into my project from the Ionic/Cordova Test Project on Github and everything worked as expected. I am not sure why they didn't install, but manually copying them over solved it.